# Experimenting with Android location services

Tags: android, android-location

I'm trying to use a sample code (http://www.hrupin.com/2011/04/android-gps-using-how-to-get-current-location-example) that I found to see how the location services work. My code compiles, however it seems that I can't get past one part in particular when the app runs. Below is the code I am using

```
package com.example.gpstest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.AlertDialog.Builder;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener, android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener {

    private EditText editTextShowLocation;
    private Button buttonGetLocation;
    private ProgressBar progress;

    private LocationManager locManager;
    private LocationListener locListener = new MyLocationListener();

    private boolean gps_enabled = false;
    private boolean network_enabled = false;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        editTextShowLocation = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextShowLocation);

        progress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        buttonGetLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonGetLocation);
        buttonGetLocation.setOnClickListener(this);

        locManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        // exceptions will be thrown if provider is not permitted.
        try {
            gps_enabled = locManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
        try {
            network_enabled = locManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }

        // don't start listeners if no provider is enabled
        if (!gps_enabled && !network_enabled) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("Attention!");
            builder.setMessage("Sorry, location is not determined. Please enable location providers");
            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", this);
            builder.setNeutralButton("Cancel", this);
            builder.create().show();
            progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        if (gps_enabled) {
            locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locListener);
        }
        if (network_enabled) {
            locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locListener);
        }
    }

    class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            if (location != null) {
                // This needs to stop getting the location data and save the battery power.
                locManager.removeUpdates(locListener); 

                String londitude = "Londitude: " + location.getLongitude();
                String latitude = "Latitude: " + location.getLatitude();
                String altitiude = "Altitiude: " + location.getAltitude();
                String accuracy = "Accuracy: " + location.getAccuracy();
                String time = "Time: " + location.getTime();

                editTextShowLocation.setText(londitude + "\n" + latitude + "\n" + altitiude + "\n" + accuracy + "\n" + time);
                progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } 
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        if(which == DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEUTRAL){
            editTextShowLocation.setText("Sorry, location is not determined. To fix this please enable location providers");
        }else if (which == DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE) {
            startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
        }
    }

}
```

The app will not get past this if statement (I keep getting the msg "Sorry, location is not d..." that it kicks out) :

```
if (!gps_enabled & !network_enabled)
```

The original statement read:

```
if (!gps_enabled &amp;amp;amp;amp;&amp;amp;amp;amp; !network_enabled)
```

however I couldn't get this to compile (eclipse didn't like all the 'amps'), so I took my best guess at what it was trying to do, but I think I butchered its meaning.

if anyone could help me get this code to work, or point me in the direction of a different example so I can play with it, that would be very helpful.

*edit* I did add all the appropriate permmisions: access coarse location, access fine location, and Internet (just for laughs, as I'm almost positive this code doesn't need Internet)

*edit* changed the '&' in my code to '&&'

*edit* added permissions manualy and everything is now working (I orignaly used the GUI option):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: Jim Lewis gave you the right correction. If you want to avoid doing that kind of mistake in the future, I'd suggest you go through the exercises at http://codingbat.com/java

Comment: correction didn't work

Comment: That's not enough information. Please let us know the new error it's giving you after you've made that correction.

Comment: its still giving the same exact one: it will not go past that if statement, even though all the location stuff has been turned on on my phone. I tried it on another phone and its doing the exact same thing

Comment: Cut and paste everything from scratch once again, but this time, put it in a simple text editor as an intermediary, to get rid of any other weird escaped html entities. Then do Project > Clean and rebuild everything. And do clear the error log before trying to rebuild again, to make sure you do are getting new errors and not just reading the old one.

Comment: just did that. It still won't seem to go past that 'IF statement'. The log isn't throwing any errors; it seems like the code is working but the problem lies in whatever changes I made from the original code (just the if statement I posted above with the amp 'stuff' (sorry, I have no ideal what that is and eclipse didn't seem to either)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copied your code into a new project, added the two required permissions to the manifest, and used the `&&` replacement Jim suggested. It works just fine on my phone.

I think you must have the permissions set incorrectly in the manifest or, probably, your phone doesn't have its GPS properly enabled for your app.

The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#isProviderEnabled(java.lang.String)) for `isProviderEnabled` states that "If the user has enabled this provider in the Settings menu, true is returned otherwise false is returned." The only exception I know of is that the method always returns false if your app doesn't declare the needed permissions.

If you're on an emulator or if you have your GPS disabled, that would explain it. Try getting your current location in an existing location-based application, like Google Maps.

Comment: Google Maps was working fine, so I'm guessing its unlikely that my location services are in fact turned off. my GPS receiver is, but it seems like it turns off after I run this app. on What permissions did you add?

Comment: Directly within the `<Manifest>` tag, I added these two permissions:
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />`
 and `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COURSE_LOCATION" />`

Comment: well this was frustrating, I did as you said and manualy added in:   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />  and it worked

Comment: I'm glad it works! I'm curious though, did you not have ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION and ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION in there before? I'm also curious if ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION is necessary.

Comment: mosck location was not. I went back to the site I listed in my question and just accidently pasted it. the first time I tested it I stil had it in there; I then went back and deleted it and it still works; bearing in mind this is on a phone and not an emulator. I find it weird that I had to actchualy go into the xml file and add it, whereas when I originaly added them I used the GUI

Comment: Ah, interesting. I seldom use a GUI for XML files, and I use Android Studio. I guess the tags must have been added incorrectly by Eclipse.

Comment: normally I just add them manually, not sure why I decided to use that option this time. I guess now we know that it could be hit or miss.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you probably need a short-circuiting AND operator `&&`, rather than the
bitwise AND operator `&` there.